# “In the menu” vs. “on the menu”  (in software)

Tags: prepositions, software, in-on

I usually see this phrase used interchangeably with the prepositions *in* and *on*. I know that their meaning isn’t the same, but I can’t think of situations where we should use one instead of another. Can anyone shed some light on any 
differences between these two:

> 1. In the menu.
> 2. On the menu.

Just to clarify, I’m talking about menus of computer programs.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on

Comment: A menu can be literal (as when dining in a restaurant), virtual (as when making a bank withdrawal at a cash machine), or figurative (as when considering any list of options). In some cases, *on* is well-understood but not *in*, and in other cases both are suitable. Where are you seeing them used interchangeably?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This comes up often, and [here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/on-in-its-semantics/71574#71574) the general answer.

In this specific case, *menu* can be viewed either physically, printed on paper to read, i.e,

- **2-Dimensional**, in which case *on* is used

  - *It's right there **on** the menu; you can't miss it.*

or informationally, like a list, or a report; this a [Container metaphor](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAContainerMetaphor.htm), i.e,

- **3-Dimensional**, in which case *in* is used.

  - *It's hard to resist the Armenian dishes in the menu.*

Quite often it makes no difference, because the information that's ***in*** the menu is also printed ***on*** the menu.

This alternation is true of **any** physical noun that can be interpreted as information, like *story, picture, book, article, paper, report, list, plans,* etc. These are collectively called "Picture Nouns" and they have very complex syntax in English.

Comment: +1 for _the information that's **in** the menu is also printed **on** the menu_; as well as _quite often it makes no difference_.

Comment: Couldn't resist clicking on the up vote...

Comment: You have often remarked in this site these dimensional analogies. Thank you for this work. It is very helpful for non native speakers. +1

Comment: Thank you, but this is is not my work -- this is Chuck Fillmore's. Everybody who speaks or wants to speak English should read his [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html). These particular facts are in the second lecture.

Comment: [Yet another answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94609/15299) to the same question, with the same answer. And [another](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/125538/15299). And [another](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70782/15299).

Comment: However, I was **on** the bus...

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to ask if a menu contains a given item *X*, one could use either of "Is X on the menu?" and  "Is X in the menu?", but by personal preference I'd incline toward *on*.

If one wants to ask if a person is sitting atop a menu, one could say "Are you sitting on the menu?" and would not say "Are you sitting in the menu?".

If one wants to ask if someone trapped a fly by closing a restaurant's menu upon it, one could say "Is the fly in the menu?" and would not say "Is the fly on the menu?".  The latter would ask (ambiguously) either whether the fly is sitting on the menu or  whether the fly is listed on the menu.

You may wish to look up *in* and *on* in a dictionary and find out what they mean.

Also see 40-some sentences using *[in ... menu](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=menu_N%20pobj_of%20in_PREP)* and a couple hundred using *[on ... menu](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=menu_N%20pobj_of%20on_PREP)*, per just-the-word.com.  A notable fraction of the *in ... menu* examples are related to constructing menus for computer applications; I don't know if that is a corpus-related artifact or a true reflection of usage.