# Should it be "...in the invoice." or "...on the invoice."?

Tags: word-choice

Should it be

> The shipping charges are **in** the invoice.

or

> The shipping charges are **on** the invoice.

Comment: Depends on the metaphor you use. Invoices are paper in origin, so they're flat, and therefore information can be _on_ them. But information can also be conceived as fluid or granular, and that requires a 3-dimensional container, so information can be _in_ an invoice as well. [We rarely notice the difference](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/74373/15299), any more than we think about gravity when we talk about a "rising temperatures".

Answer (score 3):

It appears that "**on** the invoice" is used at least twice as often, but neither would be wrong.

See the [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+invoice%2C+in+the+invoice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).