# Should we use on, or in?

Tags: prepositions

When we talk about software, should we use "on" or "in"? For example:

1. How can I import pictures in/on photoshop?
2. I installed new software in/on my windows.
3. How can export files in/on adobe premiere pro?

Comment: It depends entirely on [the metaphor theme you are using to describe the software](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/70782/15299): is it two-dimensional (which requires _on_) or three-dimensional (_in_)?

Comment: You  should attempt to make a sentence and google it. Import into, export from x to y, install x on y. Same as machines and products, which preexisted software.

Answer (score 2):

In each case I would say: neither "on" nor "in". I present my suggestions for each one:

> How can I import pictures in/on photoshop?
>
> How can I import pictures ***into*** photoshop?

---

> I installed new software in/on my windows.
>
> I installed new software ***for*** Windows.

---

> How can export files in/on adobe premiere pro?
>
> How can I export files ***from*** adobe premiere pro?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

*in* is substantially more common with single applications. *on* is closer in usage with Windows, and when coupled with *install*, *install on Windows* is more common than *install in Windows*.

#### Ngram results

[Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Windows%2Con+Windows&year_start=1990&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20Windows%3B%2Cc0) for "in Windows" vs. "on Windows", both are in use, following similar curves, but "in Windows" is more common.
[image]

[Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+photoshop%2Cin+Photoshop%2Con+photoshop%2Con+Photoshop&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20photoshop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20Photoshop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20Photoshop%3B%2Cc0) for Photoshop show a more dramatic difference. "in Photoshop" is much more common.
[image]

[Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Adobe%2Con+Adobe&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Adobe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20Adobe%3B%2Cc0) for Adobe show a similar pattern. "in Adobe" is substantially preferred.
[image]

I would posit that "on Windows" is closer in usage to "in Windows" because it is an operating system, rather than a single application. Adobe isn't a single application, but it is a company that produces commercially released applications (illustrator, acrobat, etc). So while you may do something *in* Windows, you may also install something *in* Windows.

The [ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=install+in+Windows%2C+install+on+Windows&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinstall%20in%20Windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinstall%20on%20Windows%3B%2Cc0) support this. In this context, *on Windows* overtakes *in Windows*.
[image]

Mac OS, and OS X are trickier to parse (as a comparison operating system). Interestingly, "on Linux" is more common than "in Linux", but "in linux" is more common than "on linux".