# "On" and "In" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

How can I effectively determine when I should use "on" or "in" in this kind of sentence:

"Perhaps you're not preparing a homework assignment or project, but are trying to revise for an exam. If so, you need to know exactly what is **on** your curriculum."

I wonder if I use the "in" instead. then is it ungammarical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we use on, or in?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451555/should-we-use-on-or-in) Note that a *curriculum* is an abstract / non-physical "thing", which can be referenced using either a "surface" metaphor *(**on**)* or a "container" metaphor *(**in**)*. Or even ***under***, and probably other prepositions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, as I understand after read the answer you gave me, the way we use "on" or "in" is subject to the "metaphor theme", right? 
And it is not clear what is right, and what is wong in this sentence, right?

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, I believe either works fine and should convey your intentions. There is nothing "ungrammatical" about using "in".

However, in the broader context of the English language, there is no set rule to determining "on" vs. "in". Sometimes the differences between "on" and "in" are obvious, usually when describing how physical objects relate to one another. Sometimes, the two are interchangeable (as you can see here). And finally, sometimes choosing which one is right is based on idiomatic conventions - meaning the "rule" is "how do most people say it?". For example, most English speakers would not say "What's **in** the menu?". They would say "What's **on** the menu?".

Comment: thank you @General Poxter

Comment: Does this answer the question for you?

Comment: On the curriculum just does not work here.  Something in the curriculum may be on the test.

Comment: @Jim What do you mean when you say "On the curriculum just does not work here"?
Is it ungrammatical?